# How do I find a file on Linux in an ext4 filesystem that's being written to frequently?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ext4

I've got a Ubuntu system which is writing a block to disk every 1-2 seconds. Some kind of log accruing an error.  How do I find which file it is?

I've been poring over [lsof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) output and tailing suspects with no luck. Is there a way to find it, really find it?

Comment: What makes you think something is writing to the disk every 1 -2 seconds?  Are you basing this off the drive LEDs?  It can be very tricky to get Linux to minimize writes to the disk.  Some disk flushes happen automatically every few seconds.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you can check which process is writing frequently to disk with `iotop`, then spy this process with `strace`.

Comment: yea, iotop, that's the ticket, looks like it's just  jbd2 ....

Answer (score 6):

You could use `inotifywatch(1)`. Something like this should get you closer

```
inotifywatch -v -e modify  -r /root
```

Comment: Interesting. I was not familiar with that command.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the other answers, you could also try just using `find / -mtime -1` to list files recently modified.

Answer (score 1):

I've done iostat to find what disk was getting the access, then lsof|grep  to find files, perhaps look at what looks like log files, filter out tcp or something.